# input type="date" element, custom date format

Tags: html, date, web, format

I want to know if there is a way to change HTML `input type="date"` element from this:

[image]

to something like:

`mm.dd.yyyy`

So I want to know how to change the separator.

Is there a way to do this or should I use some custom date component ?

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)  read this

Comment: @Nihal So TLDR, it can't be done as browsers format it based on locale ?

Comment: `input type="date"` is differ in each browser. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: OK, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`<input id="date" type="date" value="2017-06-01">`

Note that its also depends on browser potentional website user is using. :)

Comment: It has no impact on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need `pattern` attrib in your input to match your desired format however not all browsers support that. Workaround is to use `input="text"` instead and then use your custom code.

As per MDN:
`One way around this is to put a pattern attribute on your date input. Even though the date input doesn't use it, the text input fallback will. For example, try viewing the following example in a non-supporting browser:`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

`pattern`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern

Comment: Read that already, I am not considered about final output as I have custom function that formats the date, however I need to change the default "mm/dd/yyyy" to "mm.dd.yyyy" if possible.

Comment: May be you can use hacky workaround of using both input text/date and show hide one at a time based on if user is changing it or not and use pattern formatting in input text. And you can sanitize/remove one input before form submission.

Comment: The project is internal and I was asked to change the date format if possible, it has no value whatsoever so I'll just explain to my superior that format can't be changed by any  standard/normal means.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway.